# setting content type in rest assured

Tags: java, rest-assured

I'm trying to invoke a rest call using rest assured. My API accepts, `"application/json"` as content type and I need to set in the call. I set the content type as mentioned below.

**Option 1**

```
Response resp1 = given().log().all().header("Content-Type","application/json")
   .body(inputPayLoad).when().post(addUserUrl);
System.out.println("Status code - " +resp1.getStatusCode());
```

**Option 2**

```
Response resp1 = given().log().all().contentType("application/json")
   .body(inputPayLoad).when().post(addUserUrl);
```

The response I get is "415" (indicates that "Unsupported media type ").

I tried invoking the same api using plain java code and it works. For some mysterious reason, I cudn't get it working through RA.

```
    HttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient();
    HttpPost post = new HttpPost(addUserUrl);
    StringEntity input = new StringEntity(inputPayLoad);
    input.setContentType("application/json");
    post.setEntity(input);
    HttpResponse response = client.execute(post);
    System.out.println(response.getEntity().getContent());
    /*
    BufferedReader rd = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(response.getEntity().getContent()));
    String line = "";
    while ((line = rd.readLine()) != null) {
        System.out.println("Output -- " +line);
    }
```

Comment: Would it be possible to compare the request headers from your 2 first examples to request headers from the last example?

Comment: Option 1 :
Request method: POST
Request path: http://10.75.43.46:7001/supplierapp-war/pim/addUser
Request params: <none>
Query params: <none>
Form params: <none>
Path params: <none>
Headers:  Content-Type=application/json
Cookies:  <none>
Option 2 :
Request method: POST
Request path: http://10.75.43.46:7001/supplierapp-war/pim/addUser
Request params: <none>
Query params: <none>
Form params: <none>
Path params: <none>
Headers:  Content-Type=application/json
Cookies:  <none>

Comment: Request sent by HttpClient :
Content Type : Content-Type: application/json
Content Length : 203
Content : java.io.ByteArrayInputStream@646bfe00
content Encoding : null

Note :
I used following snippet to get header info from httpClient. 
System.out.println("Content Type : " +input.getContentType());
System.out.println("Content Length : " +input.getContentLength());
System.out.println("Content : " +input.getContent());
System.out.println("content Encoding : "+input.getContentEncoding());

Comment: Hmm that really ought to work. Try upgrading to the latest version.

Answer (score 14):

I faced similar issue while working with rest-assured 2.7 version. I tried setting both the contentType and also accept to application/json but it didn't work. Adding carriage feed and new line characters at the end as the following worked for me.

```
RestAssured.given().contentType("application/json\r\n")
```

The API seems to be missing to add new line characters after Content-Type header due to which the server is not able to differentiate between the media type and the rest of the request content and hence throwing the error 415 - "Unsupported media type".

Answer (score 9):

Here is the complete POST example using CONTENT_TYPE as JSON.

```
import io.restassured.http.ContentType;

RequestSpecification request=new RequestSpecBuilder().build();
ResponseSpecification response=new ResponseSpecBuilder().build();
@Test
public void test(){
   User user=new User();
   given()
    .spec(request)
    .contentType(ContentType.JSON)
    .body(user)
    .post(API_ENDPOINT)
    .then()
    .statusCode(200).log().all();
}
```

Comment: Good example for REST-assured testing

Answer (score 4):

Give a try
`given().contentType(ContentType.JSON).body(inputPayLoad.toString)`

Answer (score 2):

This might possibly be the case with your test. Try this.

https://github.com/rest-assured/rest-assured/wiki/Usage#avoid-adding-the-charset-to-content-type-header-automatically

> Avoid adding the charset to content-type header automatically
>
> By default REST Assured adds the charset header automatically. To
> disable this completely you can configure the EncoderConfig like this:

```
RestAssured.config = RestAssured.config(config().encoderConfig(encoderConfig().appendDefaultContentCharsetToContentTypeIfUndefined(false));
```

Answer (score 0):

For your First option can you please try adding this header too and sending the request?

`.header("Accept","application/json")`

Comment: Header "accept" is for receiving date (response) not for type of sending data (request).

Comment: @Erfankam - When sending a request you always receive a response (perhaps with empty body). Thus the advice given by Kiran is not that bad.

Comment: @whaefelinger - Yes, you are right. I will vote it up. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in previous posts there is a method:

`RequestSpecification.contentType(String value)`

I did not work for me too. But after upgrade to the newest version (in this moment 2.9.0) it works. So please upgrade :)

Answer (score 0):

I was facing something similar and after some time we noticed the problem was actually coming from the server side. Please check your call on Postman and see if when it's triggered you need to change it from HTML to JSON. If you need to do that, the **backend** may need to **force the response to be in JSON** format by adding its content type. **Even if it's encoded in JSON** you're still may need to do that.

**Thats the line of code we added:**

```
header('Content-type:application/json;charset=utf-8');
```

.

```
  public function renderError($err){
   header('Content-type:application/json;charset=utf-8');
   echo json_encode(array(
       'success' => false,
       'err' => $err
   ));
}
```

And that's what was happening on the backend:

[image]

Hope that can help somehow. :)

Answer (score 0):

```
import io.restassured.RestAssured;
import io.restassured.http.ContentType;

import static org.hamcrest.Matchers.is;
import org.testng.annotations.Test;
import static io.restassured.RestAssured.given;

public class googleMapsGetLocation {
    @Test
    public void getLocation() {
        RestAssured.baseURI = "https://maps.googleapis.com";
        given().param("location", "-33.8670522,151.1957362")
            .param("radius", "500")
            .param("key", "AIzaSyAONLkrlUKcoW-oYeQjUo44y5rpME9DV0k").when()
            .get("/maps/api/place/nearbysearch/json").then().assertThat()
            .statusCode(200).and().contentType(ContentType.JSON)
            .body("results[0].name", is("Sydney"));
    }
}
```

Comment: While this code may answer the question, it is better to explain how to solve the problem and provide the code as an example or reference. Code-only answers can be confusing and lack context.