# How to pass parameter "context": {"description": "some_value"} in REST Assured

Tags: rest, restful-url, rest-assured

I need to pass parameter to do POST on a endpoint

For key:value pair I do as below

param("key", "value")

How to achieve for below parameter object

"context": {
    "description": "some_value"
  }

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are 4 types of HTTP post method which is specified by "Content-Type" Header.Normally content-type value is "application/x-www-form-urlencoded" and the content of request body is just like

```
name=nameValue&age=10
```

However the format you need is just like JSON.So maybe the JSON-type POST can meet your need.Just set Content-type Header to "application/json" and the content of request body is like

```
{"name":"name","age":10}
```

and the way used in rest-assured can refer to this question [setting content type in rest assured](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26976624/setting-content-type-in-rest-assured)

reference [application/x-www-form-urlencoded or multipart/form-data?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4007969/application-x-www-form-urlencoded-or-multipart-form-data)